# svn checkout with netbeans returns an error

Tags: svn, google-code

I have removed a data directory from my java source code. now when i try to commit source then i get the following error.

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Working copy is corrupt
Commit failed (details follow):
Entry for 'directory' has no URL
```

i get the same error when i remove a file. what is the reason. i am checking out on google code project website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which data directory did you removed? The ".svn" folders ? If yes than you should checkout a fresh working copy and continue working there.

Comment: there was a datadata directory in the main folder created by mistake. not the .svn directory.

also if i remove a java file i am not able to commit.

Comment: Ah...If you like to remove a file you need to do this in relationship with SVN. In other words you have to tell Subversion that you like to remove a file. (svn delete) and not using operations systems command or IDE commands for that. If you accidential delete a file you can do an svn update on the file to restore it and remove it later by svn.